# Responding to a custom scheme url with SwiftUI with a Window, not a WindowGroup

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an app that uses Window, and not WindowGroup, for the main window. Before I made this change, the .onOpenURL function was working fine. When I switched to a single window, the onOpenURL function stopped being called.

How can I respond to requests to open URLs for my app using Window?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that onOpenUrl **does not** work on Window, only WindowGroup. Why, I don't know. This is on macOS, I haven't tried it on iOS yet.

In my case I need to respond to deep links to validate emails, accept invitations, etc., and my main window is a Window not a WindowGroup.

My solution is to create a WindowGroup that just responds to the various requests, displaying a "processing" view as needed. It's not ideal, because in most situations this could happen completely transparently, but as it's a rare occurance, and if there is a failure notification is good, I'm going to leave it.

It's also possible to do this with an AppDelegate, show a notification the user can click on, etc., but... maybe another time.